# Select a list of item from dataset, that have maximum sum of item.quality in limited sum of item.time

Tags: algorithm

I have a dataset which have each item with 3 properties. Id, waitTime, Quality(out of 10). 
Like

> [ {Id: 1, WaitTime: 5, Quality: 6}, {Id: 2, WaitTime: 21, Quality: 9}, .....]

What will be the best algorithm for selecting list of items with below mention criteria:

- Sum of selected item's WaitTime can not be greater then some number X
- Sum of selected item's Quality should be maximum
- There should be unique IDs in the selected list

PS. I am looking for an exact answer, approximation can be done in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), with the WaitTime being the weight, X is the knapsack size, and Quality is the value you're trying to maximize.

You can find different approaches to solving a Knapsack problem in the above link, depending on your constraints and problem size. One popular approach is Dynamic Programming.